# https Redirection issue with whmcs

Tags: .htaccess, whmcs

I have a whmcs installation in a /whmcs and wanted to force https to my entire website, so i added a .htacess with this code below in the root of my website :

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that whmcs have some issues when modifying something, and also my customers could not attach files on their tickets.

Their support told me to add a .htaccess in /whmcs to override the directives in the root .htacess
I tried many times without success, that's why i am here asking for help.

I have two choices :

1- adding a .htaccess to /whmcs to ignore the redirection made in the root .htacess.

2- modify the root .htaccess to ignore the /whmcs subfolder

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the `/whmcs` folder from your rule as

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(?!whmcs/) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I don't know what's the problem with WHMCS in particular, but it always give me a "moved permanently" apparently it implement its own layer for https redirection and it caused an infinite loop (maybe)

Comment: Are there other rules in your htaccess? Have you placed any rules inside the whmcs directory? If there's an htaccess there can please post that too.

Comment: I have other rules for redirection but none on the /whmcs ... the other rules aren't https related

Comment: Please post your complete htaccess for the rules could be interfering without you realizing.

Answer (score 0):

As the other response mentioned, you can try to exclude the rewrite from your whmcs folder, and this seems like a plausible solution.

Something you may want to check is in the WHMCS configuration itself.  If in WHMCS > Setup > General Settings you have a non-SSL URL for your System URL and an SSL URL for your System SSL URL, you can get looping.  To avoid this, if you are wanting to force SSL across the board, change your System URL to be https://yourdomain and hit save.  WHMCS should set only the System URL, and every call to WHMCS will be SSL, and if not, WHMCS will handle the redirection.